# Recycler view data coming under text view when data item increases in recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I a creating a chat appliction.In chat room activity,the recycler view item is coming under text view.I mean when data item increases, it is coming under text view.

[image: Below is the screenshot]

activty_chatroom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.boosterfoxindia.foxindtracker.ChatRoomActivity">

    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:text="" -->
        <!--android:id="@+id/tvChat"/>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rvCM"
        app:stackFromEnd="true"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/chattextbox"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter message..."
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_send_white_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
               />



        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am a beginner in android application,therefore i am not aware that where am i wrong,Please help me

Comment: please post your item.xml ....some changes in item.xml require

Comment: which item.xml, i did'nt get you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to make more changes what you required to do is Give an `id` to `Linear Layout` like this `android:id="@+id/LLMain"` and give it to `Recycler View` using this property `android:layout_above="@+id/LLMain"`.And also give `height` `match parent` to `Recyclerview`.

> Like this XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LLMain"
        app:stackFromEnd="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="7">
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change your `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` (vertical). Next your  `RecyclerView` put into new `linear_layout` and set porperty `android:layout_weight="3"`. Follow this code it's working like you want.

```
<!--<TextView-->
<!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:text="" -->
<!--android:id="@+id/tvChat"/>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rvCM"
            app:stackFromEnd="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/chattextbox"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter message..."
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_send_white_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following,
1. Add an `id` to `linear layout` containing the editor.
2. Change the `layout height` of your `recycler view` to match parent.
3. Add this attribute in your recyclerview

```
android:layout_above="@+id/editor_id"
```

4. And remove `weight sum` attribute from your editor `linear layout`

> P.S. in these cases, changing your parent RelativeLayout to LinearLayout might give crazy results on few devices, so use RelativeLayout with proper layout positioning attributes